Global AdView for all activities
I would like to finally find a solution to the "issue" which I am about to describe here.
I use AdMob ads in my Android app. I am creating them in following recommended way:
override fun initAds(activity: Activity, adLayout: LinearLayout) {
    adLayout.removeAllViews()
    val uiAdView = AdView(activity)
    uiAdView.setAdSize(getAdSize(activity))
    uiAdView.adUnitId = // AD UNIT ID HERE
    adLayout.addView(uiAdView)
    uiAdView.loadAd(prepareAdRequest()) 
}

This way, ad loads as expected - after a few seconds, the ad is displayed (it takes some time to load an ad). However, in case I go to another Activity, the process is the same, so there are few seconds during which the ad is not displayed. Can somebody provide a better approach how to solve this? All AdMob guidelines are more or less recommending to use the approach I described, but I doubt it is the best approach to work with ads.
I have thought about putting initAds to Application (singleton) class to have it available everywhere so I can obtain the same adView for the different activities. However, the AdView creation requires context, so this would not work.
Another approach would be to reimplement the app completely using fragments and have only one Activity, which would create the AdView, however I do not have possibility to reimplement the whole application. Thank you for your ideas and advices.

My approach is the same. If you reimplement the whole application as a single activity with multi fragment, then you will face the same problem. Or you can put all the banners in the main activity...
